# Setting array of tags to MLFlow registered model

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

I have a model registered in ML Flow and would like associate a list of tags to that model.
But when i looked at the reference APIs, it looks like we can add only one tag at a time with a single http request.

```
https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#set-registered-model-tag
```

Is it possible to create an array of tags and associate that with model in a single http call ?
Like how we do during model creation API ?

```
https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#create-registeredmodel
```

Comment: do you need to use REST API or can also use Python API?

Comment: Rest API is what we are preferring !!